# Number recognition of company number ranges

Tags: contacts, calls

I would like it, if it was possible to program a number range of a company in my phone as a pseudo-contact.

For example, I know my company has a thousand telephone numbers in a block. I have a number in that range, as have all my co-workers. For some, the number is ofcourse in my address book, and their name shows up correctly. However, I would like to add the whole range, so that in absence of a more specific match, it would still show my company name as the caller.

I doubt if this is possible, but should anybody know of a way, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: But if you know that range, you can check manually if it is a work number or not? I don't think there is an automated solution for it, as far as I know of course.

Comment: 6+ years later, has anybody found a way to achieve this without a ton of third-party apps? My work wants to have my cell number, but I keep my phone on do-not-disturb all the time. Somehow adding +1-abc-xyz-#### to the address book where the last four digits don't matter would work, but I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like the program suggested ([Prefixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tftbelow.prefixer)) may work. The problem will be "*For some, the number is ofcourse in my address book,*". I didn't see an "exception" to the rule on those screenshots, so how does it handle numbers that are in the block of numbers AND in the contacts.

As a workaround to an "easy way":

Of course manually inputting the numbers will work. Gmail allows more than a few numbers on a single contact. I don't know what the upper limit is, but you could just make a similarly named contact and max it out too. This would allow you to remove the exceptions from the block. Maybe use another contact software and import the contact if that interface is easier to add multiple numbers.

You could also just do it as they call. I am on 2.3.5 and after the call, when the number is not known it asks me to make a new contact or assign it to an existing one.

EDIT: I couldn't find anything out there that would do this automatically. I now know Google contacts will allow around 3000 contact numbers in one contact. Anymore than that it is starts acting odd (not saving, etc).

Using the tools that are available I have made it work by importing this block from a CSV file. Here are the steps:

1. Goto my dropbox share at [Block Import csv's](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1h6ka9fu4rm1few/s2rLIUUgly/Block_Import)
2. Download all the CSV file from that folder
   **** Might want to turn off syncing contacts on the phone at this point.
3. Go to [google contacts](http://google.com/contacts)
4. Choose MORE-->IMPORT-->CHOOSE FILE and choose the csv file (Block Import.csv)
5. Import (this may take a little while for google to respond depending on your connection speed) A new group will be created called "imported M/DD/YY
6. Go to that group and choose all the contacts. (check box on the top left)
7. MORE -->MERGE CONTACTS-->OK It will only do 250 at a time. Be patient, it is very slow.
8. Rename the contact (something like "Compan Name_1" and remove it from this group and add it to "my contacts"
9. Repeat steps 6 through 8 until there are no single contacts left. There should be around 34 contacts with 3000 contact numbers in each of them.
10. Turn syncing back on if you turned it off.

While a bit manual, with patience, it does work. Now, I don't know what that will do to your phone when you try to sync it.

Comment: The Prefixer application can only change the calling number into another calling number. I want it to change to a name. I know you could add it to the contacts, but that is impractical. For example, one I would like to add is the complete +32257XXXXX range. I know this is only utilised by the Public Service Finance in Belgium. That are 100k numbers I would need to add.

Comment: I mailed the developer of the software, and he responded that in his next release (a couple weeks out), the wanted functionality would be included.

Comment: Just discovered that the maximum size for a contact is 128Kb and anything beyond that is just truncated as documented in Google's [support](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14024&topic=1284986&ctx=topic) page. Just FYI